# Rockwool vs Fiberglass insulation

Tags: insulation, basement, remodeling, basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

I'm currently finishing my basement and I'm stock between what to use on rockwool or fiberglass.

Based on my research rockwool is better than fiberglass but it is hard to install so its more complexity. I'm more inclined on choosing fiberglass but my pushback is it has a problem with moisture and prone to molds. Is there any way to avoid it? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IF you're concerned about moisture in general you are best off to design the insulation so that moisture won't end up stuck in the insulation in the first place. This means proper ventilation, vapor barriers, moisture barriers, site grading, etc. For housing usage, consider the moisture resistance of rockwoool as a last piece of protection if your other mitigation fails.

Personally I think rockwool is very easy to install. It offers good moisture and fire resistance, good noise reduction, and higher R-value per inch. The main downside to it is cost. I went rockwool for my basement remodel based on all those factors.

Comment: Thank you @KMJ for your thoughts. I've talked with my handyman and he said Rockwool is horrible to install especially about the itchiness that it causes. Do you have a unique way to avoid those installation problems?

Comment: I've never had an issue with ending up itchy from installing rockwool. Fiberglass is the one that always leaves me itchy. Either way, if you have no preference and your handyman has a preference, you should probably go with the material they can work well with even if it's not the best.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much. I appreciate it!